# Difficulty in understanding how to include covariates in random forest for timeseries data

Tags: r, time-series, random-forest

I read this tutorial on how to use random forest for forecasting using timeseries data ( https://petolau.github.io/Ensemble-of-trees-for-forecasting-time-series/ ), and I have some difficulties to understand two things.

First thing. Let's say I have a timeseries not stationary, with both mean and variance changing over time. In other tutorials using random forest for timeseries I have seen it's important to make in stationary, so differencing and detrending. Here I understand they are detrending and considering the lag as predictor, which makes sense to me as in my case the previous value is supposed to be one of the best predictor of the subsequent one and just differencing would make the mean stable but won't allow me (and random forest) to take this predictor into consideration. If I consider lag as a predictor could I avoid differencing two subsequent values, did I get it right?

Second thing. I understand they are using the trend with train data, particularly the lag in the value of interest and Fourier components. Then once they study these components on the training data in order to forecast what happens next they create lag and Fourier test variables to forecast the y value. If I got this right (?), what I don't understand is how one could include covariates into this RF model. For example they have in the dataset temperature etc, which may improve the accuracy of the train model in describing the train data. But how can you use covariates to make a forecast, as you don't have covariates for the period of time you are going to predict? Because for example I guess the temperature in the last week of the training data may be similar to that of the forecasted period, should I try to study the trend of covariates and use their predictions for the period i aim to forecast, in order to include these predicted values in the model with which I want to predict my y of interest?